# Cálculo de média retornando undefined quando não se passa arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
(function(){

console.log(media())

function media() {

    let total = 0
    let qtd = arguments.length

    for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {


        if(typeof arguments[i] !== "number") {

            return "Digite valores Validos"

        }

        total += arguments[i]
        return (total  / qtd) || 0

    }
}

})()
```

Quero entender porque quando a função é executada sem parâmetros ela mostra `undefined`, e queria saber como posso fazer pra que quando ela retorne o mesmo, mostre uma mensagem de erro ou algum `console.log`.

Comment: Você está dando um `return` dentro de um laço `for`, não faz sentido. Qual a sua intenção com o código acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código irá retorna duas referência a `undefined`.

Sendo a primeira referência a chamada da função imediata declarada na linha #1.
Já a segunda referência sendo a chamada da função aninhada: `media()`.
O motivo do retorno da referência a `undefined` da função `media()` é juntamente nessa linha:

```
for(i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
```

A condição de teste do loop **for** está: *enquanto `i` for menor que `qtd`*.
Sendo `qtd` a quantidade de argumentos passados para a função `media` e `i igual a 0`, então quando a função não receber nenhum argumento temos: `qtd igual a 0`.

> Zero não é menor que zero, e sim igual.

Isso faz com que o loop **for** não seja executado, fazendo ser executada a próxima instrução depois do loop **for**, sendo essa instrução uma soma com um valor inexistente - pois não houver passagem de argumentos, sendo `arguments[i]` inexistente, esse valor inexistente é avaliado em `undefined`.
Sabemos que qualquer operação com `undefined` é resultante em `undefined`. Logo o retorno da função é `undefined`.

Para tratar esse retorno, antes da instrução do retorna da função, podemos fazer uma avaliação da expressão `arguments[i]`, por exemplo:

```
if(arguments[i] == undefined) console.log("Houve um erro")
```

Fazendo assim o tratamento, mas é claro que há uma vastidão de outras possibilidade de tratamento.